# How to increase th range of integers in C?

Tags: c

I tried to solve the Small Factorial problem on SPOJ and got 'Wrong answer'. I wrote the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int t,i, num;
unsigned long long int fact=1;

scanf ("%d", &t);

while (t-- >0) {

    fact=1;

    scanf ("%d", &num);

    for (i=num; i>0; i--) {
        fact*=i;
    }
    printf ("%llu\n",fact);
}

return 0;
}
```

This code is not finding factorial for large inputs like 100. What are the changes  required?

Comment: Use an external library, like e.g. [this one](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: Note that [100! is a very large number with 158 decimal digits](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100%21).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg can't do that on SPOJ

Comment: This problem can't be solved using integer type. `100!` contains over 150 digit. Think upon elementary school mathematics and storing result in a string.

Comment: Also depending on how large you want the values to be, you can use `long double`.

Comment: You don't have to use C on SPOJ. In some other languages it's a one-liner. If you want to use C, you need to implement your own bignums.

Comment: @n.m.; Best two [solutions](http://www.spoj.com/ranks/FCTRL2/) are in C.

Comment: @haccks Fastest, not best. CPU cycles are cheap, programmer's time is expensive.

Comment: @haccks [here](http://ideone.com/h00cKW) is a very fast C solution. I leave it to you to decide if it's "good".

Comment: @n.m.; May be its a fast solution but not a good one :)

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++ you have the maximum allowed range from -2^63+1 to +2^63-1 which is for `long long` data type. As you can see this range is still too small to store >20 digits.
You have to use a char array to store single digit per array index.
one way to do this in C++:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int t;
    char a[200]; //array will have the capacity to store 200 digits.
    int n,i,j,temp,m,x;

    scanf("%d",&t); //enter total elements
    while(t--)
    {
       scanf("%d",&n); // enter no. one at a time
       a[0]=1;  //initializes array with only 1 digit, the digit 1.
       m=1;    // initializes digit counter

       temp = 0; //Initializes carry variable to 0.
       for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
       {    
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            {

               x = a[j]*i+temp; //x contains the digit by digit product
               a[j]=x%10; //Contains the digit to store at position j
               temp = x/10; //Contains the carry value that will be stored on later indeces
            }
             while(temp>0) //while loop that will store the carry value on array.
             {
               a[m]=temp%10;
               temp = temp/10;
               m++; // increments digit counter
             }
      }
              for(i=m-1;i>=0;i--) 
              printf("%d",a[i]);
              printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The 64 bits range is not a maximum (you could have C implementations with only 32 bits numbers)

Comment: C99 version supports 64 bits. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Indeed in `<stdint.h>` but I am not sure that every freestanding implementation of C99 should have it (it is mandatory in hosted implementations)